# shutdown: /run/initctl: No such file or directory

Tags: debian-wheezy, upstart, sysvinit

I updated my server to Debian wheezy and played around with it. After a while I wanted to restart and encountered the error

```
shutdown: /run/initctl: No such file or directory
```

I searched on the web and found out that initctl comes from upstart. Even though it is not installed according to aptitude and the `service` command of sysvinit still works. I appreciate any help.

Comment: For me `reboot -f` works, but it is no real solution to the situation.

Comment: Thx for the `reboot -f`. Good tip. After further googling, a hard reboot is supposed to fix the issue, but it hasn't. I have also run `mkfifo /run/initctl` which stops the _No such file or directory_ error, but still doesn't shut the system down. I now get `init: timeout opening/writing control channel /run/initctl`. I have compared the `/run/initctl` just created, with the one on my working RPi, and they look identical: `prw------- 1 root root 0 Jan 1 1970 /run/initctl`.

Comment: I feel like we're in the same situation, I tried all of these as well and still no luck :D

Comment: I do not know what your problem is but mine seems to stem from the fact, that my server is virtualized and not a managed one.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Mine is a virtual machine too, using [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page).

Answer (score 7):

> I searched on the web and found out that initctl comes from upstart.

This error is what you get from research by search engine, rather than manual page.

The name is actually `/run/initctl`.  Upstart has a `/sbin/initctl`.  The two are completely different things.  The former is a FIFO that is used to send control commands to process #1.  The latter is a program file.

Originally, (Linux's clone of) System V `init` would create, in process #1 at boot time, a FIFO named `/dev/initctl`.  Programs such as `telinit` operated by opening that FIFO and writing messages to it that process #1 would read and act upon.

Systems such as Upstart, Joachim Nilsson's `finit`, and systemd provide *compatibility shims* that create a FIFO in `/dev/initctl`, listen for messages, and translate the commands from System V concepts into the finit/Upstart/systemd equivalents.  So tools that expect the System V `init` program to be running can still open that FIFO and write commands to it.  (Not all init systems provide such shims, though.  And if you ask the Debian System V `init` people they'll tell you that this is a poorly documented internal API that programs that aren't part of the System V bundle shouldn't really be using in the first place.)

Then, a few years ago, the Debian System V `init` people decided that the FIFO was going to move from `/dev/initctl` to `/run/initctl`.  So they changed their `init` to create it there, and changed all of the tools that come with their `init` — such as `shutdown`, `halt`, `telinit`, and so forth — to look for it there.

They only told the developers of one of the other systems though.  So when non System V `init` systems are managing the system, they are still mostly providing their compatibility shim FIFOs at `/dev/initctl`.  If one mixes a System V `init` tool with such a non-System V `init` system, then the tool will try to open the FIFO in its new location whilst the system is providing it in the old location.

The workaround should, by now, be obvious: A quick symbolic link does the trick.

```
ln -s /dev/initctl /run/initctl
```

And it lasts until the next reboot (when presumably one has restarted the system into a saner configuration that doesn't mix init systems up, and that will attempt to make the FIFO itself).  Roger Leigh, one of the maintainers of the Debian System V `init` package, pointed this out in 2012.

Note that it isn't really necessary to use the System V `init` tools, at all.  The lack of a compatibility shim FIFO on many init systems is not that big a deal.  systemd, Upstart, nosh, and other systems all tend to provide *their own* versions of tools such as `halt`, `reboot`, `telinit`, and so forth, *anyway*.  These tools talk the native protocols of their respective systems and don't use the `initctl` FIFO at all.  systemd's shims talk the relevant D-Bus protocols to process #1, directly.  Upstart's shims generate the relevant upstart events, directly.  nosh's shims send the relevant signals to process #1, directly.

All of that fumbling around in the other answer and the comments boils down to two points:

- If you boot with `/bin/bash` as process #1, rather than some actual init system, then *of course* there's not going to be an `initctl` FIFO anywhere.  As aforementioned, it's the init system that creates it.  Afresh.  At every bootstrap.
- And it's the init system that responds to it.  Creating the FIFO manually with `mkfifo` doesn't magically bring into existence *the server that is supposed to be listening at the read end of the FIFO for messages*.  Which is why utility programs' subsequent attempts to then send messages down the FIFO don't work.

How you managed to get Debian 7 into a state where it's using the System V `init` tools but is running another init system at the time is a different kettle of fish.  It's quite possible to do this, especially when one is *in the middle of switching* init systems.  This really wasn't all sorted out for Debian 7, and there are some strange states that a system can get into.  It's not all smooth and finished in Debian 8 (as it stands), even.  Fortunately, this wasn't your question.  ☺

### Further reading

- Scott James Remnant and James Hunt.  [`initctl`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/initctl.8.html).  Ubuntu manual pages.
- Robert Millan (August 2011).  [*please consider moving `/dev/initctl` to `/run`*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=638019).  638019.  Debian Bug Tracking System.
- Joachim Nilsson. [README](https://github.com/troglobit/finit/blob/master/README.md#rebooting--halting).  finit.
- [*systemd-initctl.service*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-initctl.service.html).  freedesktop.org.
- Roger Leigh (January 2012). [*systemd: Please use /run/initctl for sysvinit compatibility*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=657979).  657979.  Debian Bug Tracking System.
- Robert Millan (January 2012).  [`debian/patches/93_run_initctl.patch`](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/sysvinit.git/tree/debian/patches/93_run_initctl.patch).  alioth.debian.org.
- [`halt`, `poweroff`, `reboot`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/halt.html).  systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Scott James Remnant.  [`reboot`(8), `halt`(8), `poweroff`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/reboot.8.html).  Ubuntu manual pages.

Answer (score 1):

I was having *exactly* the same issue with a raspbian wheezy that I am running on a [RPi emulator on qemu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22239/qemu-rasbian-on-os-x/28477#28477). I appear to have solved the issue for my particular setup. Whether it works for you is another matter. I hope that it does. I will be honest and say that I am not sure what the issue was, or how it fixed itself, but I have documented everything that I did, and not missed out any steps.

#### Preamble

I had set up an emulated Raspberry Pi using [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), using these two guides<sup>1</sup>:

1. [Installing QEMU on OS X](https://github.com/psema4/pine/wiki/Installing-QEMU-on-OS-X), and then;
2. [QEMU – Emulating Raspberry Pi the easy way (Linux or
   Windows!)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22239/qemu-rasbian-on-os-x/28477#28477)

#### Experiencing the issue(s)

Upon *first* booting `qemu` with the command (note the use of `init=/bin/bash`)

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -hda 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

once the system had booted, I found, like the OP, that the `halt` command would not run, instead giving the error:

```
init: /run/initctl: No such file or directory
```

I then ran (courtesy of [I got a error flag "init: /dev/initctl: no such file"](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/i-got-a-error-flag-init-dev-initctl-no-such-file-219080/))

```
mkfifo /run/initctl
```

which stopped the `No such file or directory` error, but still didn't shut the system down, instead giving the error

```
 init: timeout opening/writing control channel /run/initctl.
```

I compared the `/run/initctl` just created, with the one on my working RPi, using `ls -l /run/initctl` and they looked identical:

```
prw------- 1 root root 0 Jan 1 1970 /run/initctl
```

#### Possible solution

I pressed on with [the guide](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/)'s steps regardless, after a `reboot -f`. Now this next step is where the fix occurred I believe. I started the qemu RPi with a "normal" boot, **leaving out** the `init=/bin/bash`

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

Wheezy booted into the `raspi-config`. I merely changed the pi user's password and the hostname, and hit  and the system rebooted. I then started the qemu RPi again with

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

It booted into the tty login screen. I logged in, ran `startx`. After `X` started I ran `sudo shutdown -h now`. It shutdown and halted as expected, without any `init:` errors.

#### Conclusion

The booting of the (virtual) device without the `init=/bin/bash` appeared to fix the issue. Whether this was the equivalent of a *hard boot* which is supposed to fix the issue<sup>2</sup>, or if it was a combination of the `mkfifo` and the `reboot`, I am not sure. Not my best answer I know, but hopefully it will help.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is way too much info to attempt to summarise, in case of link death. However, the setup is largely irrelevant to the issue of the OP.

<sup>2</sup> According to [can't reboot debian](http://forum.slicehost.com/index.php?p=/discussion/183/cant-reboot-debian/p1) and [systemd-sysv, sysvinit: problems rebooting when switching between systemd-sysv and sysvinit](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663219)